# Geometry Node Transform distorting my mesh

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes, distort

I'm having a strange issue that when I use geometry node transform to rotate an object on the z axis it distorts the mesh, whilst if I rotate without the geometry transform node everything is okay? Can anyone help?

Cheers

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must scale reset with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd>

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked.  You're a legend